# ¿Como colocar un texto a la derecha y un boton a la izquiera?

Tags: css, html5, web, aplicación-web

estoy en un proyecto y Tengo un texto en el lado izquierdo, pero no puedo posicionar un botón al lado derecho y que queden alineados.ojala me puedan ayudar.

```css
.right{
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width: -50%;
    height: -50%;
}

.boton{
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #0271CD;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 1px;
 
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <a>
        <h1>Proyectos</h1>
    </a>
    <div class="right">
        <a href="./Nueva-Empresa.html" class="boton" target="_blank">
            <i class="fas fa-  plus-circle"></i> Nuevo</a>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola algo así? https://jsfiddle.net/7d2cLjo4/17/

Comment: claro algo asi, pero que el boton quede al otro extremo, nose si me explico

Comment: Las  medidas no pueden ser negativas, esos `-50%` hacen que las reglas sean ignoradas. Por otra parte, el encabezado toma todo el ancho disponible y hace que el botón se baje. Flota solo el primer elemento (el de la izquierda) y el otro se colocará automáticamente a la derecha.

Comment: @RenattaQuiroz entiendo, asi? https://jsfiddle.net/7d2cLjo4/19/ igual verifica la respuesta que te dieron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tambien puedes hacer uso de flex aplicado al contenedor de los elementos

```css
.contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="contenedor">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
  <button class="btn btn-primary ml-4" type="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

La etiqueta `<h1>` incluye un salto de linea al final de la etiqueta si no recuerdo mal.

Colocando dos `<divs>` con `float:left` deberías conseguir lo que buscas.

Con tan solo esto ya lo he logrado:

```css
#h1{
    float:left;
}
.right{
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width: -50%;
    height: -50%;
}

.boton{
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #0271CD;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 1px;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mi web de pruebas</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="container">
            <a>
                <div id="h1">Proyectos</div>
            </a>
            <div class="right">
                <a href="./Nueva-Empresa.html" class="boton" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-  plus-circle"></i> Nuevo</a>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```